# Will Power automate support getting more than 5,000 items from SharePoint, and can we apply paging?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, flow, power-automate, list-view-threshold

I have a document library inside SharePoint where the document library contains 1 million documents. Each document has an expiry date.

Now I want to create a scheduled flow which runs daily and get all the documents which have their expiry date = Today.

Now it is expected that the documents which have their expiry date = Today will be more than 5,000 items.

So can anyone guide me on how can I implement this inside the scheduled flow? If I want to do so using CSOM, I would do these steps:

1. CAML query to get the document which have their expiry date = Today + Implement paging to avoid the 5,000  threshold issue.

So inside Power Automate, how can I implement this?

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint REST API returns maximum 5000 items in one API call. In Power Automate flow, there are few ways to get more than 5,000 items:

1. Using Pagination (from action settings) - This setting is specific to few actions
2. Using the Do Until method

You can find detailed steps for above methods in below articles:

1. [How to get more than 5000 items from SharePoint Online in Flow](https://alextofan.com/2019/08/22/how-to-get-more-than-5000-item-from-sharepoint-online-in-flow/)
2. [Get more than 5000 items from SharePoint with Power Automate](https://www.tachytelic.net/2020/04/get-more-5000-items-sharepoint-power-automate/)

---

Also, there is limitation on how many items will be returned using pagination. It is based on the [license/plan profile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config#performance-profiles) you are using:

[image]

For detailed limitations of Power Automate flows, check below documentation: [Limits for automated, scheduled, and instant flows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config)

Comment: thanks for the helpful reply.. so since we have 1 million records, so what i am trying to achieve is not supported inside Power automate.. and it will be easier to writ CSOM code inside console application that run daily i do the data retrieval and checking ?

Comment: any advice on my above comment?

Comment: (Maximum) How many expired items/documents will be returned at a time? And Yes, it should be easier to retrieve more items using CSOM/console application as you will have more control using programming.

Comment: in the near future we could have 5,00,000 items in one report..

Comment: Hi @johnGu, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.